# How to declare Jquery var inside bind function

Tags: jquery

I have the following simple script

```
$('.numberdiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  var tester = $(this).text().substring(1);
  console.log('The option with value ' + $(this).text().substring(1)); 
  console.log($tester); 
});
```

Which results in

```
> The option with value 0.12
> general.js?oqank0:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: $tester is not defined
```

I have also tried first declaring `var tester` outside of document.

Probably a newbie mistake, but I am not able to see what. :) My goal is check if `$this` is less than or greater than 5.00, so maybe there is even a better way?

Comment: Where are you defining `$tester`? I can only see `tester` in your code sample

Comment: inside the function, and also just `var tester` before '(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {'

Comment: `$tester` and `tester` are two separate variables.

Comment: To make it explicit: you have a typo in your code. You wrote `$tester` but meant `tester`.

Comment: Newbie error, thank you both for the lesson!

Comment: _"My goal is check if $this is less than or greater than 5.00, so maybe there is even a better way?"_ One cannot simply suggest if there is a better way, if we have no way in knowing what you currently have.. ;)